# Shouldn't the 'dom-if' element be hidden?

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

Today I was working on transitioning some of my work over to Polymer 2.0. I noticed that when using the new `<dom-if>` element that it is not hidden in the DOM, and actually receives inherited styles. This led to some layout problems. You can see an example of the problem here:
http://jsbin.com/roqirezuvi/edit?html,output

As a work-around I added a style to hide all `dom-if` elements, like so:

```
dom-if{
  display: none;
}
```

It seems like this should be default styling for the element, unless I am missing something.

For clairty, I am using the docs here:
https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/templates#dom-if

I tried both methods mentioned, the results are the same.

Comment: If you use dom-if template it hides all tags inside it and I think you don't need to add this styles.

Comment: I understand that if the `if` attribute on the `dom-if` is false that all of the content of the `template` element inside the `dom-if` will not be added, but what I'm saying is that the `dom-if` element itself is not being hidden regardless of the state of the `if` attribute. Leading to it potentially becoming visible on the page.

Comment: Yes, `dom-if` exists on page cause it must render a code inside it when property in `if` condition become to `true`. it is not a problem cause user don't see it and you don't need to hide it by adding some specific selector. Relax man

Comment: But if you look at the example you can see that the content generated by the `dom-if` being true is not even in the `dom-if` element itself. So it is unnecessary to have it visible at all, and causes layout problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to that [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/templates#dom-if), it is suggested to wrap all the necessary HTML in a tag inside the `dom-if`, be it `<template>` or any other HTML element like `div`. That way you would not have to hide the `<dom-if>` using styles yourself.

```
<dom-if>
  <template>
    ...
  </template>
</dom-if>
```

Comment: Here is an updated JS bin that hopefully clarifies that I understand the need to wrap the content in a template element and that actual content shouldn't be in the dom-if itself. http://jsbin.com/kagesiwofo/edit?output. Notice that the dom-if element still appears (and takes up space!) when all I did to style it was to give it a background color. You're welcome to play with the js bin. I'd love to see that red box disappear.

Comment: You can use `:not()` pseudo class like `*:not(dom-if)`. Doing so will not hide the `dom-if` but remove the padding from it. http://jsbin.com/zosapefido/edit?html,output